# what's the meaning of this sentence? “ We assign it astronomical authority when it delivers astrological results.”

Tags: meaning, sentence

Every single one of us has failed to evidence willpower. Yet we continue to believe in it. **We assign it astronomical authority when it delivers astrological results.**

I can't understand the meaning of the bold part. Thank you in advance

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you unable to parse it into clauses with identifiable subjects and verbs? Is there a word whose meaning you didn't look up in a dictionary but do not understand? Your questions show zero research.